# Multiple if Statements using reference number

Tags: java, if-statement

The code below compiles and does its job, however lets say I needed to added another 100 if statements that uses a reference. Whats the most efficient way to write multiple if statements?

```java
public String getForceDetails(String ref) {
    if (ref.equals("IW1")) {
        setupForces();
        return (ForceDetails.get(0).toString());
    } else if (ref.equals("SS2")) {
        setupForces();
        return (ForceDetails.get(1).toString());
    } else if (ref.equals("WB3")) {
        setupForces();
        return (ForceDetails.get(2).toString());
    } else if (ref.equals("IW4")) {
        setupForces();
        return (ForceDetails.get(3).toString());
    } else if (ref.equals("WB5")) {
        setupForces();
        return (ForceDetails.get(4).toString());
    } else if (ref.equals("SS6")) {
        setupForces();
        return (ForceDetails.get(5).toString());
    } else if (ref.equals("SS7")) {
        setupForces();
        return (ForceDetails.get(6).toString());
    } else if (ref.equals("WB9")) {
        setupForces();
        return (ForceDetails.get(7).toString());
    } else if (ref.equals("IW10")) {
        setupForces();
        return (ForceDetails.get(8).toString());
    } else {
        return "\nNo such force";
    }
}
```

```
private void setupForces()
{
    ForceDetails.add(new starShip("IW1","Twisters",200,200,ForceState.DOCKED,10,0,0,false));
    ForceDetails.add(new starShip("SS2","Enterprise",300,200,ForceState.DOCKED,0,10,20,false));
    ForceDetails.add(new starShip("WB3","Droop",300,100,ForceState.DOCKED,0,0,0,false));
    ForceDetails.add(new starShip("IW4","Wingers",200,400,ForceState.DOCKED,20,0,0,false));
    ForceDetails.add(new starShip("WB5","Hang",400,300,ForceState.DOCKED,0,0,0,true));
    ForceDetails.add(new starShip("SS6","Voyager",450,200,ForceState.DOCKED,0,15,10,false));
    ForceDetails.add(new starShip("SS7","Explorer",120, 65,ForceState.DOCKED,0,4,5,false));
    ForceDetails.add(new starShip("WB9","Hover",300,400,ForceState.DOCKED,0,0,0,false));
    ForceDetails.add(new starShip("IW10","Flyers",200,100,ForceState.DOCKED,5,0,0,false));
}
```

Comment: `ForceDetails` is a `java.util.List`??

Comment: Is ForceDetails a list of hardcoded strings ? If so this looks largely like a Map of strings to strings. If you can find your key, then extract your value and call setUpForces() (but does setUpForces() set up ForceDetails differently in different scenarios?)

Comment: @luiscla27 yes, it is a java.util.*

Comment: @luiscla27 please check above i have added more of the code

Comment: Use the strategy pattern.  The @ping.shantanu answer below describes one way to implement a strategy pattern.

Comment: @unknown, thank you, can you please post also the `starShip` class??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious choice would be a switch statement over ref:

```java
switch (ref) {
    case "IW1":
        setupForces();
        return (ForceDetails.get(0).toString());
        break;
    case "SS2":
        setupForces();
        return (ForceDetails.get(1).toString());
        break;
    // etc.
}
```

If the code to execute always looks the like this (calling `setupForces()` and getting the n-th element of `ForceDetails`) you could also use a map that lets you retrieve `n` (`Map<String, Integer>`) which you populate with key-value-pairs like "IW1"->0 and "SS2"->1 etc.
The map solution also has the charme that you do not need to repeat the code that is basically equal for all cases which would be rather inconvenient if you have to change this later.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no inbuilt solution to that. What you can do is create a `Map`  of condition -> result and return the value to the key.

```
Map<String, String> mapCondToRes = new HashMap<>();

public String getForceDetails(String ref) {
    setupForces();
    return mapCondToRes.get(ref);
}
```

You can check for validations and put more conditions very easily and elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

In the existing code, *each* invocation of `getForceDetails` with a valid `ref` causes adding of 9 entries to a collection of starships `ForceDetails`.  It is doubtful that this behaviour is intended, possibly a lazy initialization of `ForceDetails` was implied.

Next, to get rid of the multiple `if` statements using of the map is definitely more preferable than converting into `switch` statement and copying the same multiple calls to `setupForces()`.  It could make sense to create a map `Map<String, starship>` instead of the list and populate it in `setupForces` (so there's no need to have a separate map of references to the index in the list):

```java
Map<String, starShip> forces = new HashMap<>();

private void setupForces() {
    forces.put("IW1", new starShip("IW1","Twisters",200,200,ForceState.DOCKED,10,0,0,false));
    forces.put("SS2", new starShip("SS2","Enterprise",300,200,ForceState.DOCKED,0,10,20,false));
// ... add other starships mapped by their ids
}

public String getForceDetails(String ref) {
    if (forces.isEmpty()) {
        setupForces();
    }
    return Optional.ofNullable(forces.get(ref))
        .map(starShip::toString)
        .orElse("No such force found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [java stream](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-in-java/#:%7E:text=Introduced%20in%20Java%208%2C%20the,to%20produce%20the%20desired%20result.&text=A%20stream%20is%20not%20a,Arrays%20or%20I%2FO%20channels.), you should read about them, you'll find it useful later as you progress on Java.

For the following code, I assume you have a `getter` for your "key" values inside your `starShip` class (`"IW1"`, `"SS2"`, `"WB3"`...).

This code also assumes that you cannot change your current `List` approach, If you can, a `Map` would be a even better.

```java
private static final String NO_FORCE = "\nNo such force";
public String getForceDetails(String ref) {
    String result = ForceDetails.stream() // <-- It's even faster if you use `parallelStream` however is known to have non-thread-safe issues
        .filter(starShipItem -> Objects.equals(starShipItem.getKey(), ref))
        .map(String::valueOf).findFirst()
        .orElse(NO_FORCE)
    ;
    if (NO_FORCE.equals(result)) {
        return NO_FORCE;
    }
    setupForces();
    return result;
}
```

Also, I recommend you to take a look at [hackerrank challenges](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/), you'll learn a lot more there.

Comment: It's an interesting solution because it helps avoid duplication of starship ids, but if my assumption about lazy initialization of `ForceDetails` is true, it may be worth to invoke `setupForces` _before_ streaming.  Also, finding in a stream is generally O(N) plus overhead on getting the stream, while map-based solution is faster with O(1) complexity.  Minor comments: there's no need to have two `return`, `String::valueOf` may be replaced with `starShip::toString`.

Comment: Actually, I didn't pay attention to method names... so I didn't realize that he's adding items to `ForceDetails`  again and again at every call. I just transformed the same code the OP posted into a faster approach without the issue of having to add an extra `If` for every new ship Id. Agree with you that `setupForces` should be called before `getForceDetails`.